# Testing word is in language L = {a^n-1b^n} using stack

Tags: c++

I am writing a C++ function that implements a stack to test if a word is in language L = {a^n-1b^n}. Words that exist include b, abb, aabbb.

I have seen many postings with regards to testing a word being in a language where L = {a^nb^n} and I am just wondering how to go about this when the n's are not equal.

The code that I have written works but I feel that I am taking the easy way out with regards to making sure the word is not in a format like aba bababa abababa etc. I have implemented this test outside of the stack but feel there should be a way to do it in the stack.

The reason I say this is because I later have to take the function bool isInLanguageL(string w) and use the following header instead bool isInLanguageL(queueType &w). I have been having trouble trying to convert the code I previously had with string w to queue w.

```
    //function prototype
    bool isInLanguageL(string w);

    //function to see if the word exists in the language
    bool isInLanguageL(string w) {

    //creating counters for the a's and b's 
    int countPush = 0;
    int countPop = 0;

    reverse(w.begin(), w.end()); //putting the b's infront  

    //creating the charachter stack
    stack<char> charStack;

    //checking the word for an illegal format such as aba or bab
    for (int i = 0; i < w.length(); i++) {

        if ((w[i] == 'a' && w[i + 1] == 'b' && w[i+2] == 'a') || (w[i] == 'b' && w[i + 1] == 'a' && w[i + 2] == 'b')) {

        cout << "This is an illegal format of a word in language L and therefore: ";
        return false;
        }

        else { //if the word is a legal format then continue onto stack creation

        //adding the b's to the stack and counting them simultaneously
        if (w[i] == 'b') {

            charStack.push(w[i]);
            countPush++;
        }

        //popping off the stack everytime there is an a and counting simultaneously
        else if (w[i] == 'a') {

            charStack.pop();
            countPop++;
        }
     }
  } 

    //if the stack is not empty and a = b-1 then the word exists
    if (!charStack.empty() && countPop == (countPush - 1))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

int main() {

//introduction
cout << "The language rule is L = {a^n-1b^n}" << endl;

//creating an empty string for the word and condition variable for exit
string word = " ";
int exit = 0;

while (exit == 0) {

    //getting word from the user
    cout << "\nWord: ";
    cin >> word;

    //calling function to check if word exists in L
    if (isInLanguageL(word)) {

        cout << "The word exists in language L" << endl << endl;
    }

    else
        cout << "The word doesn't exist in language L" << endl << endl;;

    cout << "Would you like to exit (1-yes/0-no): ";
    cin >> exit;
  } 

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

If anyone can just lead me in the right direction with regards to testing for whether the word is of a legal format (not aba abababa bababa), it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As a mathematician, you'd know how to solve this. `x in  {a^n-1b^n} ` is equal to `a x in  {a^nb^n} `. Reduced to a solved problem, done.

Comment: Do you have a reference on parsing, lexing, regular languages or compiler design?  There should be examples for this.